# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

Estoy realizando un api rest con Node.js express y mysqlx devapi
El problema surge al realizar la consulta a la bd debido a que se realiza de forma asincrona y cuando intenta mandar el siguiente resultado me manda error.

> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

[image: Error en consola]
este es el código que utilizo => Router

```
app.get('/equipos', (req, res, next) => {
    equipo.getEquipos((err, data) => {
    res.json(data);
  });
});`
```

<--MODEL-- >

```
equipoModel.getEquipos = (callback) => {
  myTable.select().execute(function(rows) {
     callback(null, rows);
  });
};
```

Adjunto mi código [Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PhsDD6xs8mursqfcsqD9m4rx5Rx5pLFG?usp=sharing)

---index.js----

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

//middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//routes
require('./routes/administradorRoutes')(app);
require('./routes/equipoRoutes')(app);


app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('server on port: 3000')
})
```

---Route--
Aqui es donde se manda el header

```
const equipo = require('../models/equipo');

module.exports = function(app) {

  app.get('/equipos', (req, res, next) => {
    equipo.getEquipos((err, data) => {
      res.json(data);
    });
  });

  app.get('/findEquipo/:nombre', (req, res) => {
    equipo.findEquipo(req.params.nombre, (err, data) => {
      res.json(data);
    });
  });

}
```

---Model---

```
var mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi');
var myTable;

mysqlx.getSession({
  user: 'root',
  password: 'maxammo1299',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 33060
}).then(function(session) {
  myTable = session.getSchema('torneobd').getTable('equipo');
});

let equipoModel = {};

equipoModel.getEquipos = (callback) => {
  myTable.select().execute(function(rows) {
    return callback(rows[0].objid);
  });
};
```

Comment: Los headers se envían antes de ejecutar cualquier código. Tu error es parecido al de PHP en el cual dentro de un if o else quieres modificar los headers y eso no está permitido.

Comment: Puedes agregar una parte del código en tu pregunta en dónde manejas los headers, los link se pueden perder con el tiempo y no servirá a otros usuarios con el mismo problema.

Comment: Angel, en el Modelo veo que que no exportas la variable `equipoModel` (puede que no la estes mostrando). También, cuando haces la llamada del `callback` solo devuelves un parámetro en vez de dos, como se muestra en el Route `(err, data) => { ...`,  esto puede que te este dando el problema que estas teniendo, aunque no debería porque devolvería un null.